# android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 - What is this object, I don't get it

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1)

I see this object named and referenced in many code samples I see.  Specifically, I have seen it in the params for the new ArrayAdapter constructor.

The problem is, in every single example, I don't see an object deceleration for this anywhere in any xml layout or code anywhere.  Either every single example is missing it accidentally, or I am just missing something here.  I'm also including books in here too.  Specifically, "Professional Android 2 Application Development" by Wrox press.  Shame on this book for not explaining what this means, however has it used everywhere.

Could someone explain to me what android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 typically would mean.  Sorry, I just don't get it.  Is it an object?  If so, what?

BTW, I'm a senior developer with 11 years in .NET.  This is my first time using Eclipse, Java, and Android.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1

Comment: **duplicate question** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1

Answer (score 0):

simple_list_item_1 and simple_list_item are List Item layouts built into the platform to be used with ListAdapter. Otherwise you define your own ListAdapter layout.

Comment: Thanks, I've since figured it out.  I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why some samples had this object reference 'simple_list_item_1' yet, trying to figure out where it existed in my project and what the name of the object should be and where it should be declared in a layout.  That is where the confusion was. I "finally" get it now.  Day 1 of Android development complete :)