# what is android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

In all the examples I've seen they just use "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" when creating an ArrayAdapter.
What is android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Is it just the name of a layout file called simple_list_item_1.xml or is it the id of the TextView required for the array adapter?

How do I see the content of the file or use my own file from my res folder?

```
public class MyClass extends ListActivity {
private String[] titles = {"Test"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles));
     updateList();
}
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`android.R.layout` contains all of the publicly available layouts that the Android OS uses to display various items. `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is, as it's named, just a simple layout to display a snippet of text. It saves you from having to write simple layouts when using adapters and also affords you the native look and theme of the system in your application with minimal effort.

I have included the source [from the GitHub mirror](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) of the [android.git.kernel.org](http://android.git.kernel.org) repo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

Comment: thanks for the info, I knew what the R.layout.file stood for I just didn't know they were distributed with all androids, for some reason I thought it was a sample layout from the API demos

Comment: This code is actually simple_list_item_1.xml. Layout file containing just one TextView.

Answer (score 2):

There are some Inbuilt Layout XML files in Android API
and there are listed in this Image

[image]

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is one of them 
it is use for simple display of String

You can use Your Own Layout instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

for example If you have made a layout row.xml then you can use as

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, titles));
```

Answer (score 0):

The android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is an inbuilt layout resource and it displays a single string. 
If you want to use your own layout file then you can use

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.<your layout filename>, titles));
```