# Android Layout Templates Usage

Tags: android, templates, layout

Is there a document or series of documents that gives specific information on standard Android layout templates. I have been looking for several hours and not found anything.  I have seen [R.layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#) that gives some scant info and constant values.

I understand how to create custom layouts, I have made many in my apps but I cannot find comprehensive info on the xml equivalents or usage info for Android standard templates such as simple_list_item_1, simple_list_item_2, simple_list_item_multiple_choice, etc

Comment: If you want the actual code for these xml files, see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079344/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't, at least no to my knowledge. There is an official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html) but its missing a lot of information though.

Hope this helps...