# Populating ListView with ArrayAdapter force closes

Tags: android, listview, crash, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to use the following code to populate a ListView using a predefined array of strings:

```
String[] schedule_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test_schedules);

// Populate the ListView using the array of schedule names
ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(schedule_names));
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listView, als);

adapter.add("Test");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But it force closes unless I comment out `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` (which obviously means the ListView isn't populated at all). It seems the reason is a `NullPointerException`.

Why is this?

Comment: Error log will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listView, als);
```

...the second parameter of the constructor should not be your `ListView`, it should be a layout with a `TextView`.

Try replacing `R.id.listView` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks! What is `simple_list_item_1`?

Comment: Nevermind, it turns out this was explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1 so I'll link from here for future reference.

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, that's a good link explaining the pre-defined `android.R.layout` resources.