# set size of android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am new to android and I made an auto - complete textview and it is working , but my problem is the text size in the `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` is bigger than `simple_dropdown_item_1line` .

So is there a way that I can set the **text size** or set the size of the `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` ? .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom layout, or copy android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1 contents create a new xml and pass this xml to AutoCompleteTextView

sample:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"    
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

srikanth gr's answer is outdated.  This answer is best.
[What is "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1)

A link to the file in github is:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml