# Android: positioning items in ListView menu in java?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am really new into Android development, so I am sorry if this question may sound funny to some of you. 
I need to center the items of my ListView Menu just for the sake of aestheticism, but I really don't know how since the code is written only in java without the use of XML.

```
    package com.example.mysqltest;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = {"ProductList", "example1", "example2", "example3", "example4", "example5"};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String local = classes[position]; 
        try {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.mysqltest." + local);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a Custom Adapter and customize the layout the way you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own Adapter :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
       private LayoutInflater inflater;
       private List<String> data;
       public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> data){
              this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              this.data = data;
       }

       public int getSize(){
              return data.getSize();
       }
       public Object getItem(int position){
            return data.get(position);
       }

       public View getView(View convertView, int position, ViewGroup parent){
              View v = convertView;
              ViewHolder h;
              if(v == null){
                   v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, false);
                   h = new ViewHolder();
                   t.tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
                   v.setTag();
              }else{
                   h = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
              }
              String s = (String) getItem(position);
              h.tv.setText(s);
              return v;
       }
       public class ViewHolder{
              TextView tv;
       }

}
```

I don't really remember by heart because of the autocompletion in Eclipse, but it should look like this.

Your my_adapter.xml is where you will place your TextView everywhere you want, you will be able to add more, like ImageViews and others TextViews.

And to call it it's simple :

```
     MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, myList);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the layout you are passing to your adapter here:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
```

This piece is the layout of the row:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1) answer that explains what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only written in Java, you have to supply an XML layout for the Adapter to inflate. In your case, you've got `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. Where you set it here:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
```

As you've not posted the content of `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` - I have to assume that it's just a `TextView` that's contained within it. As such, you can quite easily align text with something like the following:

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texviewid);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Failing that, you could always set it within the XML of `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and not worry about it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just write this code before setting adapter,here lv is your listview
    lv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);