# Cannot resolve symbol issues in making a stopwatch

Tags: android, stopwatch, chronometer

(Keep in mind i'm very new to coding) I'm having an issue when coding a stopwatch app, I've scavenged this site and found no solution to my issue, comparing my code to another user's who attempted the same tutorial, i found that they are the same, yet I am getting several unresolved symbols when to my knowledge, everything is correct...

Ok, i updated the file with some corrections, now im not having any more errors with start/stop, but i have new errors with the m(start/stop/etc)Listener code...

(Here's the Main Activity Java File)

```js
package com.jackson.eason.stopwatch.;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import your.package.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Chronometer mChronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button;

        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.Chronometer);

        // Watch for button clicks.
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        button.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_format);
        button.setOnClickListener(mSetFormatListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_format);
        button.setOnClickListener(mClearFormatListener);

        View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChronometer.start();
            }
        };

        View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChronometer.stop();
            }
        };

        View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            }
        };

        View.OnClickListener mClearFormatListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChronometer.setFormat(null);
            }
        };
    }


    }
```

(Also, here's my xml file, which Android Developer says is fine)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Chronometer android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:format="@string/chronometer_initial_format"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:paddingTop="30dip"
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="start">
        <requestFocus />
    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="chronometer_stop">
    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="reset">
        </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/set_format"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="format">
    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/clear_format"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="clear_format">
    </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Comment: The import `import android.R;` is wrong. This imports a general `R` version that has no idea about your project resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are importing the wrong `R` class. `android.R` is different from the `R` file generated for your app and referencing your resources, it is the R file from the framework itself, allowing you to use convenience resources, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1) for an example.

```
import android.R;
```

replace that with

```
import your.package.R;
```

Also, as Thanos suggested, put your listener declarations inside the `onCreate` method.

**UPDATE** :

When I said `your.package.R`, it was just an example. The package depends on what you chose it to be when creating your project, but judging by the code you provided, you probably need import `com.jackson.eason.stopwatch.R`

Secondly, you need to declare your listeners first before you use them. If you don't, if you call `setOnClickListener(mClearFormatListener)` but `mClearFormatListener` is declared after, the compiler doesn't know about `mClearFormatListener` yet so it shows a compilation error. The below code should work.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get references to views
    mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.Chronometer);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_format);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_format);

    // Declare the listeners
    View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.start();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.stop();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
    };

   // You forgot to declare a listener for set format in your updated code
   View.OnClickListener mSetFormatListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO : set the format
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mClearFormatListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.setFormat(null);
        }
    };

    // Assign the listeners to your buttons
    button1.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
    button3.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
    button4.setOnClickListener(mSetFormatListener);
    button.setOnClickListener(mClearFormatListener);


}
```

One last thing : in the notation `mVariable`, m stands for "member", meaning a member variable of a class, as opposed to a variable inside a method. Since your listeners are only declared inside a method, we usually don't use `mListener` but rather `listener`. Of course, this is just a naming convention and it will not prevent the code to compile and run ;)

Comment: Much appreciated,now, what exactly do I put in place of "your"?

Comment: Ok, so i added the listeners inside the oncreate, which fixed the error for the start/stop/etc, but caused new errors for all of the m(stop/start/reset/etc)Listener lines

Comment: Can you update your question with the changes you made and the error you're getting ? We'll get there ;-)

Comment: Sure, but i have class now, and will add them in about 90 minutes

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if there are still things you have problem with.

Comment: Thanks for the help! There's only 2 errors left, and it's an error with mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.Chronometer); and an error on button4.setOnClickListener(mSetformatListener);

Comment: Actually, only one error now, With the mChronometer class... Not sure what is wrong...

Comment: And I'm not sure how to set the format for the mSetFormatListener

Comment: OK, all errors gone now, but when i run the app and tap a button, there is no display of time..... how can i fix this??

Answer (score 0):

I think that all the listeners should be inside a method. Am I wrong? Try placing them inside the onCreate method (at the very end of it).