# Create a listView adapter from hashtable containing an object as value

Tags: java, android, listview

im  very newbie in android & java
and I have a hashtable that contains values. 
values are objects (task class that has 3 attributes code,title,state)

I'm trying to get the data of all tasks in hashtable and show them in list view

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.output_list);

ArrayList<task> arr = new ArrayList<task>(tasklist.values());

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, arr );

list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

`tasklist` is hashtable name

`task` is an entity class

```
public class taskDAO {
    public static final Hashtable<Integer , task> tasklist = new Hashtable<Integer , task>();

    public static final boolean addTask (task t){

        tasklist.put(t.code,t);
        return true;

    }
```

**Exception**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

I tried many things but since i dont get how this works i can't figure out 
a solution,
any help?

Comment: I am not seeing the reason for the `Hashtable`. [Start here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: bro i know u don't see a reason, but i have a reason , so the question is how to show a listview for that particular hashtable

Comment: You haven't told us what you want the adapter views to look like...

Comment: I have a linear layout with a Listview in it thats all!

Comment: Exclamation marks are not necessary. You need to understand what an Adapter actually does. It loads one "row view" for each "item" in the "array" into the "ListView". No part of your question explains what this "row view" should look like.

Comment: i implemented the toString in the entity class and it's now working, thank you mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you that the second argument to the Adapter needs to be a TextView layout, not a ListView layout (or whatever the `list.xml` file contains)

If you implement a `toString` method on your `task` class (which you should rename to `Task` because of Java naming conventions).

Then, you'll see data when you use

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
    arr);
```

For more details about that layout, see [What is "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1)

Comment: very close man , but it shows entities.task@5555555   , how to show the title and status?(task properties)

Comment: You did not read the answer completely. You need to [implement `toString`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4#29140403)

Answer (score 0):

change your adapter generic type String to your class name that is `task`.so that it look like

```
ArrayAdapter<task> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<task>(this,R.layout.list, arr );
```

And ofcourse make your class name start with capital letter like `TaskDAO` not `taskDAO`

Comment: I know about conventions and best practices but i'm just learnin, i came from php so somestuff are wierd tbh, anyway this does not work, app crashes