# Null Pointer Exception on EditText to String

Tags: android, string, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in which I get numbers and need to convert them to a `float` but still get the same eror - `Null Pointer Exception`.

This is my code:

```
public class Basic extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic, container, false);
        Spinner spinnerLenght = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerLenght);
        spinnerLenght.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> lenghtAdapter;
        lenghtAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.basic_string_lenght));
        lenghtAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerLenght.setAdapter(lenghtAdapter);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String itemLenght = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        EditText editTextLenght = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextLenght);
        float floatLenght;
        floatLenght = Float.parseFloat(editTextLenght.getText().toString());
        float result_mm = 0;
        if (itemLenght.equals("mm")){


            result_mm = floatLenght * 1000;
        }


        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), (int) result_mm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

This is logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.dusan.unit, PID: 5181
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at com.example.dusan.unit.Basic.onItemSelected(Basic.java:46)
                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:956)
                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:920)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried it on a `double` too.
I also had problem with `null = ""`
I read a lot about this but can`t find solution.

Answer (score 0):

1)Check if you wrote correct id of your editText;
2)Find your editText in onCreateView from inflated layout or make your layout view as class variable and then find your edit text from her in onItemClick

Comment: I use tabbed activity here.And i don`t have onCreate here i have onCreateView and someone told me that is problem.Is that right?

Comment: @DusanCulum The tabbed activity does have `onCreate`. The fragment in a tab has `onCreateView`, but that is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

#### Main problem

You are using the wrong ID and class.

`EditText editTextLenght = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextLenght);`

The correct ID is `android.R.id.text1`.
The correct class is `TextView`.

See [What is "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1) since that is the layout you set in the adapter.

---

#### Alternate solution

If the problem is `parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`, then don't use that.

If you want to access the data in the adapter, then move it to a scope that you can access using a member variable

```
public class Basic extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> lenghtAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic, container, false);
        Spinner spinnerLenght = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerLenght);
        spinnerLenght.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        this.lenghtAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.basic_string_lenght));
```

Then, use `getItem` method rather than trying to find the view

```
float floatLenght = Float.parseFloat(lenghtAdapter.getItem(position));
```

Also, please spell length correctly

Comment: Still have problem logcat:  java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.example.dusan.unit.Basic.onItemSelected(Basic.java:39) ( String itemLenght = spinnerLenght.getSelectedItem().toString();)

Comment: `spinnerLenght` is not accessible within `onItemSelected` from your question, and that code you pasted doesn't match the question. So that is a **new** error, not the same

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.dusan.unit, PID: 24497
                                                                        java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
                                                                            at com.example.dusan.unit.Basic.onItemSelected(Basic.java:44) 44 is this :EditText editTextLenght = (EditText) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

Comment: That makes sense... It's not an editable text field. Please try the *alternate solution*, then.

Comment: But in Spinner i chose mm cm or m so i need it first as string for   if (itemLenght.equals("mm")){


            result_mm = floatLenght * 1000;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Look at main(you asked) problem, you want convert the `number` to `float` from the `EditText`.

First import:
`import android.widget.EditText;`

```
EditText editTextLenght = (EditText) View.findViewById(R.id.editTextLenght);

floatLenght = Float.parseFloat(editTextLenght.getText().toString());
//this code used in java programs.in android you can use below

try{
   float floatLenght =  Float.valueOf(editTextLenght.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`float`(first letter is small) is primitive type and `Float` is wrapper class use to conversion from `string` to `float`.
You don't need to change other code.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at com.example.dusan.unit.Basic.onItemSelected(Basic.java:53) that is float floatLenght =  Float.valueOf(editTextLenght.getText().toString());