# ListView and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

When we build a ListView in android studio, we need to use an ArrayAdapter.

What is the task of second argument in constructor of ArrayAdapter ?

I cannot understand what is `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` used for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "android.R.layout.simple\_list\_item\_1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1)

Answer (score 0):

This layout describe how the item list looks like.Maybe you want every item contain a text view and image.You should specify these details in this layout.

Answer (score 0):

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is a layout in which the data from your ArrayAdapter gets populated(added).

Answer (score 0):

This is the id of the layout that you need to use for populating each of the item in the list. If it says **android.R.layout** that means you are going to use one of the standard android layouts. **simple_list_item_1** This is the name of the file which will populate each row of the list. try changing this to **simple_list_item_2** to see how the layout in list changes.

You can also use your custom adaptors and custom layouts(which would be in majority of the cases in day to day apps).

For full list of standard layouts available Go [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html)

Answer (score 0):

This argument defines how list items would appear in **ListView**, There are many layouts you can also try them out or you can make your own **custom layout** to modify apperance of **listitems** in Listview by using **CustomAdapter**.

Answer (score 0):

1.create custom layout name custom_layout.xml & paste bellow code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

2. Use like R.layout.custom_layout instead of  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Comment: you can now use text size, color and so no