# ListView item long click listener throwing a null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView that lists all the files in a folder into the ListView as an array. I seem to have a problem with long selection of the ListView's single item in that, when i long click an exception is thrown that  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference`
I want to achieve a change of color for the selected child view Background and the Text color of the TextView inside that View...
Here is the complete code i tried to implement my `AdapterView.OnLongItemClickListener`

```
public class video_player extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    ListView filelist;
    List files;
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.medias_combine);
         filelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filelist);
        files=new ArrayList<>();
        //Defining folder to read files from
        File store = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
          File[] myfiles=store.listFiles();
         //Adding filenames to the ArrayList
        for(int i=0;i<myfiles.length;i++){
         //Adding a file filter
            if(myfiles[i].isFile()&& myfiles[i].getName().contains(".mp4")){
                files.add(myfiles[i].getName());
            }
           //Build the ListView
              ListAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files);
                filelist.setAdapter(myadapter);
            //ListView Item long item click listener
             filelist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                       for(int i=0;i<filelist.getCount();i++){
                         //Problem is in this loop
                           if(position==id){
                               view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                               TextView mytext=(TextView)filelist.getChildAt(position);
                               mytext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6600cc"));
                           }else{
                               view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6600cc"));
                               TextView mytext=(TextView)filelist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                             //  TextView text=(TextView)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                               mytext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                           }
                       }

                       return true;
                   }
               });
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`getItemAtPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView#getItemAtPosition(int)) gets the data associated with the specified position in the list, not a `View`.  Instead of  `TextView mytext=(TextView)filelist.getChildAt(position);` use the `view` provided, which is [actually the item being clicked](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener#onItemLongClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)) within your `ListView`. Try this instead:

```
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==id){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                TextView mytext=(TextView)view;
                mytext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6600cc"));
            }else{
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6600cc"));
                TextView mytext=(TextView)view;
                mytext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        

        return true;
    }
```

Since,you use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to inflate the view item within the ListView, you can type cast it as a `TextView` and  call `setText()` on it.

Note: [`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` consist of just a `TextView`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml). Refer to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3663745/11200630).

Comment: View has no method to fetch text unfortunately

Comment: Typecast it as a TextView

Comment: Post the code, that way it will be easier

Comment: Please check the answer again. I have edited it.

Comment: It worked, am accepting your answer and i hope to see you more often here at SO

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with this line `TextView mytext=(TextView)filelist.getChildAt(position);`   `mytext` is `null` because when code tries to get the view from the viewList the assigned value is null so try to find the reason for this.